# Why that person was framed into murder at the end of the series?

Tags: ending, good-girls

Since this is a question about the ending of the series, obviously there are spoilers below. And yes, I've done some basic search in google before asking, for example by [reading this article](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/2570872/good-girls-ending-explained-annie-arrested-jail-fingerprints-gun-series-finale)

At the end of season 4 (and it seems also the end of the series), Beth is shot in the shoulder with the same gun that was earlier used to kill her workmate. The gun is left at the place of the crime and later police find the fingerprints of her sister Annie on the weapon, which results in her arrest.

But why would Rio (the gang leader who was all the time having a hold over the "good girls") do that? He was using this gun (with Beth's fingerprints) as leverage over them, threatening to send it to police if they wouldn't follow his orders. The article that I've mentioned above suggests the reasons why it was Annie's fingerprints instead of Beth's on the weapon (Annie was willing to take the blame for her sister), but that doesn't explain why the gang would put Annie in jail, especially now, when Beth has won a place in the city council, presenting herself as a "tough, anti-crime mom" - having sister in jail doesn't look too good, no?